# accessing value from SQL parameter to use it for an XML attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to build an xml by using the parameter value for the attribute.

```
Declare @price int =100

Declare @xml xml = '<Product DiscountPrice= "{sql:variable("@price")}"   />'

Select @xml
```

I get the following error.

> Msg 9410, Level 16, State 1,
>   XML parsing: whitespace expected'

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `sql:variable` is only used within `.query()` calls.  This is how you can create a snippet of xml using your variable:

```
Declare @price int =100
declare @xml xml;

set @xml = (select [@DiscountPrice] = @price for xml path('Product'));

Select @xml
```